# Storing duplicate lists in redis

Tags: redis

I'm trying to determine which way to track duplicate lists.

Currently I have strings which should not be duplicated example

```
superduper duplicate 333
superduper duplicate 555
superduper 557
```

I want to track that "superduper duplicate" 333 is the same as 555. Once a duplicate is found I just need to track both 333 and 555 together and there can be more than 2 duplicates found.

Each item has an ID number with it to identify which one was the duplicate found.

If I use a sorted list or Set I cannot easily store the id field with the string.
If I use a list it cannot store the id fields.
I have not looked into score set.
I'm using a multithreaded program so I cannot depend on order of inserts.

Any ideas for a structure that would help me store this information in Redis.

Comment: "If I store as a hash I exceed the 1000 threshold and it causes major cpu" you are referring to IDs in a hash ?

Comment: Hash fields inside one hash

Comment: May be am missing something, I understood that the strings are keys in Redis and you are trying to index the duplicate IDs inside hashes , but what is the 1000 threshold you are reaching ? according to this https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/redis-db/eArHCH9kHKA , the limit is your RAM.

Comment: I was reading that Storing more than 1000 fields in a hash causes performance issues. I'll be storing millions of rows in one hash, so let me know if this will be a problem?

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm still confused by your question. Do you want to find a solution for storing a super long list with strings that could be duplicated, or find a solution for storing a super long list with strings that count **not** be duplicated?

Comment: Based on my current understanding, have you tried `sorted set` with `id` as score, since your `id` looks like an int?

Comment: I edited my original question hopefully that makes more sense.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution I came up with. I'm open to anyone with a better idea.

I have a duplicatelist which is a score (zset) storing the string and id to that string.

```
Duplicates  (zset)
- "superduper duplicate" 333
- "superduper duplicate" 555 *wouldn't be added but here for example purposes
- "testing"  123
- "tester"   101
- "testing"  999 *wouldn't be added but here for example purposes
```

Then I store duplicate information in another list

```
DuplicatesListId (Set)
- 333
- 123
```

Then I create & keep a list of all id's which have additional mapping duplicate id's.

```
DuplicateId:333 (Set)
- 555

DuplicateId:123 (Set)
- 999
```

This allows me to look up and get all items in DuplicatesListId and then get each duplicate information using a specific key because I don't know the id that originally was duplicate.
The "Duplicates" (zset) list is then temporary for purposes of tracking which items are in the dup list and it's corresponding id.